# Change panels / views based on button click

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel

I would like to implement the following WinForms user-interface, with two buttons at the top that allows the user to toggle between two views.

So, when I click the **1st button** ("Show User Profiles"), the three panels below should show the three different user profiles (with some content fetched from database), like so...

[image]

And when I click the **2nd button** ("Show Chat History"), the three panels below should show the three different chat histories (with some content fetched from database), like so...

[image]

**What is a good approach (either dynamic or static) to implement this kind of structure in C# / .Net?** Is there a cleaner or at least more efficient way than my crude method below:

- Layout three sets of controls for the three Profiles
- Layout three sets of controls for the three Chat-Histories, overlapping on top of
  the Profiles' controls.
- Change visibility of the controls based on which button is pressed.
- For example, if 1st button is clicked, Set **Visibility=false** for all the controls related to Chat-History, and Set **Visibility=true** for all the controls related to User-Profiles.

Comment: Instead of two buttons on the top to switch the view with multiplpe pannels why dont you use a tab control ?

Comment: Does a "tab control" switch between entire Forms, or can I make it switch between my own customized selection of items?

Comment: a tab control would give you a separate set of panels. Its the obvious way to do it, but if you want to overlay panels and control the visibility you can, and its fine. I have a content viewer that displays either images or text depending on the mime type of the content, and that context switching occurs without user interaction, so it makes sense there to put the image control on top of the textbox and set it visible if the mime type is image/jpeg. Where a user is going to make the choice tho, I would use a tab control.

Comment: @John: I'll give that a shot. Perhaps you can make that an answer.

Comment: @John: But I wish to change the view of ALL three panels at once upon the tab selection, not have the user navigate tabs of one panel at a time. Is that still possible with tab control?

Comment: yes, sure, you would just put 3 panels in each tab. ill add an answer with something of a tabs tut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a tab control would give you a separate set of panels. Its the obvious way to do it, but if you want to overlay panels and control the visibility you can, and its fine. I have a content viewer that displays either images or text depending on the mime type of the content, and that context switching occurs without user interaction, so it makes sense there to put the image control on top of the textbox and set it visible if the mime type is image/jpeg. Where a user is going to make the choice tho, I would use a tab control.

I assume you are using the visual ui to add controls. you can just drag a tab control to your form and it should by default appear with 2 tabs defined. You can add more in properties my modifying the tabpages collection. That's where you would also rename them to reflect your choices (profiles, chats). drag the tab control up where you want it on the form and size it appropriately, or dock it to fill the form. drag 3 panels into the first tab, then click on the 2nd tab, and drag 3 more in there. then proceed as you would have. When the user clicks on the chat tab the tab control will manage the view - hiding the first tab and its 3 panels. Of course clicking the first tab would make that tabPage visible again. no need for you to code anything.

I'll just add that I don't understand the design of having 3 profiles visible, and 3 chat history's. Unless your users are going to be limited to 3 friends. I would think you would be better off using a listbox for friends names on the profiles page, with a single profile panel that just filled the profile controls based on which friend is selected, and then the same list on the chat page, with a single chat panel that loaded the history into the textbox based on which friend was selected. That way you can have all the friends you want :)

and for completeness i'll suggest one more way, why should the user have to switch between tabs to view a users profile or chat history when you can provide them both in a single tabPage? You could programmatically create a new tab for each user and on that tab have their profile panel on the left, and their chat history on the right. Less context switching = better user experience. The tab control will allow you to scroll for tabs that don't fit on the form automagically(tm).

Comment: your comments above would be better suited to be included in your answer. So, instead of making comments, Edit your answer and include your thoughts there.

Comment: @John: Thanks for sprinkling in the extra UI suggestions; gave me a couple of new ideas. My example in the question was just an illustration that I thought would make it easier to ask the question. The end-application isn't exactly just a chat/profile application.

Comment: Also, update: I've begun building the tabcontrol-based layout and it seems fairly easy so far. Next step is to put in dynamic/programmatic addition of new tabcontrols!

Comment: glad to be of help. If you get stuck with that post another question! don't forget to accept an answer if it did the trick for you :)